# ssh on edge-node for azure HDInsight

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I tried deploying a HDInsight cluster with an edge node.
I used https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-hdinsight-linux-with-edge-node/azuredeploy.json for deployment.

After deployment is complete I tried ssh using following command:

```
ssh sshuser@new-edgenode.myclustertest-ssh.azurehdinsight.net:22
```

[myclustertest is the name of the cluster].

It gives following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname new-edgenode.myclustertest-ssh.azurehdinsight.net:22: Name or service not known
```

Do I need to add something to the azuredeploy.json to enable ssh access?

Looking at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-linux-use-ssh-unix I thought that

```
<edgenodename>.<clustername>-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
```

is enabled by default for external access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was in the ssh command.

I used the ssh command supplied from azure portal hoping that it would work seamlessly. I had to remove :22 from the command to make it work.

Modified command looks like this:

```
ssh sshuser@new-edgenode.myclustertest-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
```